# How do I make it so that the values from the 'combobox' can be selected?

Tags: c#, winforms

I work in Windows Forms. I have a combobox ('Departments' name) it contains a list of departments. By selecting a department in comboBox1(Staff), employees working in this department appear. But I can't select an employee, because they are not displayed

Code, filling in comboBox1(Staff). dataNames - dictionary(department name - array of employees)

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Departaments.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        this.Staff.Items.Clear();
        var dataNames = DataForComdodox.ArrNames(Departaments.SelectedItem.ToString());
        this.Staff.Items.AddRange(dataNames);
    }
}
```

Code in Form1.Designer - comboBox1(Staff)

```
this.Staff.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.Normal;
this.Staff.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.Staff.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
});
this.Staff.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(374, 84);
this.Staff.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2, 2, 2, 2);
this.Staff.Name = "Staff";
this.Staff.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 21);
this.Staff.TabIndex = 0;
this.Staff.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

I tried to change Staff.SelectedIndex = 0, after I fill comboBox1(Staff) with values, but in the end, when choosing a department, an employee was selected automatically with an index of 0

Comment: Maybe think a little bit what you are doing here: every time someone changes the selection of the combobox you clear the combobox (what is the selected item then?) and then you re-add all the items (what is the selected item then?). This doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If var dataNames = DataForComdodox.ArrNames(xx) returns a list or array of class employees, you could override the ToString() in the employee class.

```
public class Employee  
{  
    public int EmpId { get; set; }  
    public string  EmpName { get; set; }  
    public string DeptName { get; set; }  
  
    public override string ToString()  
    {  
        return $"{this.EmpId}: {this.EmpName}";  
    }  
}
```